# Preview UIWebView in iCarousel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, icarousel

I am writing a app in `Swift` where I am trying to load a preview of images using `iCarousel` of `html` pages for which I am using `UIWebView`.

Now the problem I have is I am unable to preview html pages, however when I trying to preview images, I am able to preview it.

Here is my code

```
func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {

      var webView : UIImageView!
        let webV:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
         webV.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!))
        webV.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

        if webView == nil{
            webView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:200,height:200))
            webView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        }else{
            webView = view as! UIImageView
        }

        webView.image = UIImage(named:"left-arrow.png")!

        return webView //returns image carousel
        //return webV //returns blank carousel. I want this to work !!!
    }
```

How do I achieve this functionality ?

**Edit 1**

I can preview images for 
`carousel.type = iCarouselType.Linear` screen attached.
[image]
This is how it looks

but I want it for any other carousel, say
`carousel.type = iCarouselType.CoverFlow` this is what I get
[image]
This is what I get when I am returning `UIImageView`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this functionality by using `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`

Here is the working code

```
    let webV:WKWebView!
    webV = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 200))
    var url = NSURL(string:"http://www.fb.com/")
    var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
    webV!.loadRequest(req)
    return webV
```

Also,make sure you have imported `WebKit` by adding the below line

`import WebKit`